# Import CSV file into Excel using VBA and transforming data type of specific columns prior to loading

Tags: excel, vba, csv

I have been manually using the 'Get Data from CSV' function in Excel to import a CSV file and using the 'Transform Data' option to manually dictate data type of certain specific columns before loading it.

To provide some more context, the item number column has some cells with leading 0's, alphamueric, numbers (0001, 0002, 2X345, 3E127, 56789) which I want to retain, hence I need the column in Text format. I am currently using the below VBA code to import and load the CSV file, but this is recognising the item number column as general and the leading 0's missing from those cells.

```
Sub CSV_Import()

Dim ws As Worksheet, strFile As String

Set ws = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("PO Data") 'set to current worksheet name

 strFile = Application.GetOpenFilename("Text Files (*.csv),*.csv", , "Please select text file...")

With ws.QueryTables.Add(Connection:="TEXT;" & strFile, Destination:=ws.Range("A1"))
     .TextFileParseType = xlDelimited
     .TextFileCommaDelimiter = True
     .Refresh
End With

' delete the querytable if there is one
On Error GoTo nothingtodelete
    Sheets("PO Data").QueryTables(1).SaveData = False
    Sheets("PO Data").QueryTables.Item(1).Delete
nothingtodelete:
End Sub
```

Is there a way around this in VBA? Can I replicate the 'Transform data' function which I am currently doing manually to recognising a column header - say 'Item Number' and load that column as text?

Comment: Examine the `QueryTable.TextFileColumnDataTypes` property.  Or just set up the query using Power Query, and do the transform there.

Comment: A csv file **IS** a text file. And that works here for CSV files. Please edit your question to show sufficient information so your problem can be replicated.

Comment: Thanks, @RonRosenfeld! Apologies, I had not entered enough arguments for it to consider the item number column as text format. It worked for me now. Thank you!